# Why doesn't out of range indexes throw an exception for Regex GroupCollection?

Tags: c#, regex, exception, match

Ordinarily if you try to access an array member that doesn't exist you get an "IndexOutOfRangeException".

However, for some reason, I don't get that for a Regex GroupCollection.

For example:

```
    var match = Regex.Match("", "a");
    var test = match.Groups[6];
```

Does not throw an exception, despite `match` having only 1 group.

Why does this happen?

Comment: It is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection.item?view=net-6.0) this way. Difficult to speculate about the motivation of this design decision,

Comment: "*If groupnum is not the index of a member of the collection, or if groupnum is the index of a capturing group that has not been matched in the input string, the method returns a Group object whose Group.Success property is false and whose Group.Value property is String.Empty.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.

See the [`GroupCollection` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection.item?view=net-6.0#Remarks):

> **If `groupnum` is not the index of a member of the collection**, or if `groupnum` is the index of a capturing group that has not been matched in the input string, the method returns a [Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group?view=net-6.0) object whose [Group.Success](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success?view=net-6.0) property is `false` and whose `Group.Value` property is [String.Empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?view=net-6.0).

I bolded the beginning of the sentence since it describes your current scenario: `a` regex pattern finds no matches in an empty string, the match is empty, and there is no group with ID = 6.